# 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder Error Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, azure-functions, autofac

I receive the following error while trying to inject one of my components:

> No constructors on type 'Event.Function.Components.EventComponent' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'

As you can see, I am trying to inject the following components:

```
DependencyInjection.Initialize(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<IDatabaseContext>()
                .WithParameter("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString());

            builder.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterType<EventComponent>().As<IEventComponent>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired();
            builder.RegisterType<CommentComponent>().As<ICommentComponent>().SingleInstance().PropertiesAutowired();

        }, functionName);
```

Below please find the `class` objects I am trying to inject.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IDatabaseContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{

    protected readonly IDatabaseContext Context;

    public Repository(IDatabaseContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
public class EventComponent : IEventComponent
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    private EventComponent(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }
}
```

I am using `.PropertiesAutoWired()`, which gives the following definition, and according to my understanding, should know what `IRepository` is, since it is registered in the container.

> Configure the component so that any properties whose types are registered in the container will be wired to instances of the appropriate service.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Posting it here as it will hopefully help someone else, and maybe my future self.

After posting, I realized the constructor on my `EventComponent` is private, and it should be public.

So I changed:

```
public class EventComponent : IEventComponent

    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    private EventComponent(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }
}
```

To:

```
public class EventComponent : IEventComponent

    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public EventComponent(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
    }
}
```